# How to parse numbers in strings and sort them?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of strings and I need to sort them first numerically if it contains a number and then if not sort alphanumerically.

Example:

```
const array = ["test 3","test 1","some test","another test","test 2"];
```

Expected result: **test 1, test 2 , test 3, another test, some test**

Preference for es6 solution.

Comment: How do you handle multiple numbers in a string? What's the expected result for `["9 h 1", "90"]`?

Comment: This is a special case and I have sure I won't have that issue

Comment: Is it possible that the string contain numbers > 9? Is it possible that the numbers aren't at the end of the string? What exact problem are you struggling with? Do you know how to extract a number from a string? Do you know how to sort an array using the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method?

Comment: Yes, the numbers can be higher than 9 and we can have for example this string as well "24 test". Yes I do know how to extract a number from a string and I have already used the sort method but for this case is not working well, I think I have to do some tweaks on it.

Comment: You should post your attempt so that we can help fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get a numerical value from the string or a large value to sort strings without any digit to the bottom. then sort by string.

```js
const
    getDigits = s => (s.match(/\d+/) || [Number.MAX_VALUE])[0],
    array = ["test 3", "test 1", "some test", "another test", "test 2"];

array.sort((a, b) =>
    getDigits(a) - getDigits(b) ||
    a.localeCompare(b)
);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: It's exactly this! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = ["test 3","test 1","some test","another test","test 2"];
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    let aNumber = a.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
    let bNumber = b.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
    if (aNumber.length * bNumber.length) {
        a = parseInt(aNumber);
        b = parseInt(bNumber);
    } else if (aNumber.length + bNumber.length) {
        return aNumber.length ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ((a === b) ? 0 : ((a > b) ? 1 : -1));
})
console.log(array);
```

So, you have three main cases

- **1**: Both items contain numbers. In this case you need to extract the numbers from both and compare them
- **2**: Exactly 1 item contains numbers. In this case it will precede the other value
- **3**: None of the items contain numbers. In this case we compare the items as they are

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function :

```
array.sort((a, b) => a.charCodeAt(a.length - 1) - b.charCodeAt(b.length - 1));
```